# Can you find what RFID frequency is used in a tag and then edit it?

Tags: rfid, nfc

A short background: my brother has membership at a gym that uses small RFID tags ("near field", I suppose, as you need to tap them against the spinning gate in order to open it) and after changing his membership type, he received a new tag while his old one stopped working.

I suspect the gym removed the ID within the older tag from their entree-eligible list. My question is what frequency such RFID tags usually operate at (or whether there's a way to find out), and whether can I edit its content after finding out the correct frequency (to match that of the working ID)?

Comment: There are plenty of resources on 'rfid copier' or 'rfid clone' on the internet.

Comment: I saw some that refer to 125kHz frequency. But is it likely this is the frequency used by such "RFID fob"? And even if that's a "yes", can it copy/write-protected so a simple $10 gadget like suggested won't work?

Comment: It's very likely the RFID tag has a permanent serial number which the facility puts into a whitelist when the FOB/card is handed out to a valid holder.  So once that s/n is removed from the whitelist the FOB is useless.

Comment: "or whether there's a way to find out" like measuring it? Also, I would remove the usage context from the question if I were you.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answer says, "dumb", cheap passive tags typically use 125kHz. The ID (which is a serial number) for each tag is written by the tag manufacturer during production. Nobody has any way to modify it, even the gym. They just read the number and open the door if it is in the allowed values.

More elaborated cards (like Mifare) typically use 13.56 MHz. Those have read-write zones that can be eventually updated. But they still have a read-only serial number that nobody can change, and which is commonly used for physical access. And, in any case, updating a read-write data on such tags requires the knowledge of cryptographic keys. In chinese gadgets you mentioned, the keys are well-known (test keys). I doubt any real-world use of these cards will keep the test keys (unless the people deploying the solution are as dumb as a 125kHz tag).

Anyway, knowing the carrier frequency is far from sufficient to forge your own tag. Forging your own tag requires knowing the whole protocol, and most likely some keys. In the Mifare case, for example, a big part of the protocol is kept secret by NXP (for exactly this reason), and all we know is that is encrypted in some way. So even if you manage to record the communication between the reader and the card, you won't be able to replicate it on your own.

So you have no way to workaround this and make your own pass. This is exactly what smart cards are for, by the way.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If the part used in these dumb 125kHz fobs for door access is the manufacture-set serial number, which cannot be changed according to you, then what part of them IS rewritable and what is that part even used for?

Comment: Likely, in the tag, nothing is rewriteable. What they update is a database (outside the tag) listing allowed IDs, and that the automatic door looks up when a tag is detected. It is however possible that they use the smarter kind of tags in which some information can be updated, but in that case, you don't have the knowledge of the required crypto keys to do it yourself.

Comment: "[Mifare tags] have read-write zones that can be eventually updated. But they still have a read-only serial number that nobody can change, and which is commonly used for physical access." -- well, genuine NXP ones do.  The cheap chinese clone tags often allow writes to all locations.

Comment: @Jules I don't think there are Mifare clones, since the protocol is not public. There may be cheap chinese tags writeable anywhere without protection, but certainly not Mifare-compatible. They would have their own proprietary command-set.

Comment: @dim - Mifare (or at least some versions of it) has been [reverse engineered](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/sp-14/materials/arsenal/sp-14-Almeida-Hacking-MIFARE-Classic-Cards-Slides.pdf).  Clone tags are available, e.g. https://www.aliexpress.com/item/UID-changeable-mifare-s50-chip-rfid-smart-contactless-chipset-cob-id-ic-keyfob-key-tag-fob/32913890109.html

Comment: @Jules Wow. I knew it had been somehow hacked a few years ago, but I wasn't aware you could buy clones that easily. OK.

Comment: @dim As you mentioned Mirfare: I took the plastic cover apart, and the chip looks just like the one that comes up when searching for "Mirfare Classic s50" (the image showing a chip circled by a copper-colored antenna). That means this is the Mirfare Classic s50 or there are other chips that look like this?

Comment: @TLSO Any contactless chip could theoretically be embedded under that form factor. Now, it is true that these manufacturers certainly don't produce all kind of variants of any kind of chips under all kind of form factors, so it may be an indication. So, since there are apparently blank s50 clones you can buy, as indicated by Jules, there seems to be a possibility that you can actually make your fake pass. You'll need some specific contactless reader hardware (or maybe just a NFC phone?) and some software tools, though. And probably a bit of knowledge. Google probably knows...

Comment: @dim Hey, I suspect now it isn't a Mifare. The visible side of the chip didn't say anything, but I unglued it and under it is written "4100". From what I read it should refer to "EM4100", which is a protocol for 125khz RFID chips. Are these even encrypted? Will I need a "reverse engineered" one like mentioned regarding Mifare to completely modify it as needed?

Comment: @TLSO Actually, I'm less aware of how EM4100 works, but the few I've read about it, it seems there is no security at all in the protocol, amazingly. It's complete crap and shouldn't be used for this application. So, just google "RFID 125KHz EM4100 ID Card Copier", you'll find what you want (assuming it is indeed some EM4100 chips). --- And for the record: yes, I'm shamelessly giving information on how to fraud, but hey, I'm not the one doing it, and the gym should probably use something more secure.

Comment: @dim Well, I guess I'll get one of those Chinese chipos. As I said, if I'll use it more regularly I'll put the extra cash, but currently it's like having an all-pass public transportation used MAYBE 4 times a month. If my brother wants to lend it here and there, I doubt it's a financial issue for anyone. Otherwise it's rather money spent without being exchanged for anything.

Comment: @TLSO Honestly, you don't need to justify yourself: I don't really care about the morality aspect. I don't go further than the technical matters. If there is a question that hurts my feelings (like: "how do you make a bomb?"), I don't answer. But if I do, don't need details on your reasons, as it's not my role to give an approval on this. You're a big boy, you decide for yourself.

Comment: @dim Thanks. I didn't really think otherwise, that's why I said "from a technical point". One could frankly give no further information and just ask how it might work.

Answer (score 1):

Most RFID near field tag operates at a frequency of 125kHz and will react to the reader by creating a unique magnetic signature. That signature is then translated into an ID inside the identification system.

While it is possible to emulate that signature using another card/device. You will not be able to modify your brother's card. They are cheap and disposable for that particular reason.

Note that each device provider got a slightly different protocol because they don't want cards to be cross compatible (this is how they make the bulk of their money).

Comment: You mean that the old card is not rewritable? Is that certain? And if that's the case, should buying a rewritable "blank" and copying the working ID to that one work? I can see the sell these cheap read/write Chinese gadgets with several writable fobs that look already really similar to what I'm trying to copy. I could just move the gym's logo to that one, I suppose.

Comment: Yes the old card is not rewritable and I'm almost certain. For the rest of your follow-up question, I don't feel comfortable answering it.

Comment: Because of the purpose of my question? From a technical point, the answer would be the same if I asked how to copy a fob for some system I use in my private home. From a moral point, well, me and my brother go to the gym just several times a month, really, less than half the frequency of many of their regulars, so I don't think I can say we plan on "using them". If we both were to go several times a week I'd sign up for another membership.

Comment: Although it seems this answer didn't meet OP's expectations, I don't think it deserved a downvote either. Lemme fix that...

Comment: @TLSO From a moral point, what you are doing is violating your contract with the gym and committing fraud. You may feel comfortable doing it but other people are not and Simon is perfectly justified in taking whatever position feels comfortable to Simon.